# Wrong date in email

Tags: support

Why do I receive a message that I havent checked my inbox since 2015? Why does it even generate for docs items?

[image]

Comment: Are you asking about the date or are you asking about Docs sending you notifications?

Comment: Interesting. Well no, it isnt docs that sent the email, it just happened to be at the top of the list. It just surprised me to get an email at all, with a date in the far past, while I last logged in a few days ago.